# Can successor be defined in $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$?

Tags: model-theory

I once asked whether the successor function can be defined in the structure $(\mathbb{N}, +, 0)$ without parameters. Now, I am asking whether the successor function can be defined in the structure $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ without parameters. I left out $0$ in that structure because $0$ can certainly be defined without parameters in that structure.

Comment: How is this not trivially "no"?  The sign-swapping automorphism doesn't preserve "successor", and there doesn't seem to be any internal way to tell them apart -- you need a parameter to label the sign.

Comment: A more interesting result is the $\emptyset$-undefinability of the **unit distance relation** $U(a,b)\iff \vert a-b\vert=1$. This *can't* be established by automorphisms, since all (= both) automorphisms of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ respect $U$. Moreover, since $U$ is definable by an infinite conjunction of universal sentences, we can't use EF-games either. We need a quantifier elimination argument, but $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ doesn't admit quantifier elimination so we first need to find the right expanded language. At a glance adding subtraction and a "mod $n$" unary predicate for each $n$ should do the job.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Hehehe :P. Do you know a better way to prove my comment than expanded-language-QE?

Comment: @NoahSchweber QE would be my go to approach anyway. IIRC, you're correct that adding 0,-, and a predicate for divisibility by p for each prime p gives QE.

Comment: @wnoise You should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'm afraid I should really leave it to someone who actually knows model theory.

Comment: @wnoise I don't think so, you got it exactly right. Since it's not preserved by automorphisms, successor isn't definable in $(\mathbb{Z};+)$ according to *any* logic (in a precise sense), let alone first-order logic. As an answer, your comment doesn't need any elaboration.

Comment: But if you're not comfortable with it, I can post an answer crediting you if you'd prefer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yeah, I want you to post it as an answer.

Comment: @user107952 OK, I'll do that in a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This expands wnoise's comment above into an answer; I've made it CW to avoid reputation gain for their work, and if they post an answer of their own I'll delete this one.*

The answer is **no**, the successor function is not definable in $\mathcal{Z}=(\mathbb{Z};+)$. There is a simple proof of this: the map $$\alpha: z\mapsto-z$$ is an automorphism of $\mathcal{Z}$ which does not preserve the successor operation, but all definable functions(/relations/elements) must be preserved by automorphisms.

Note that this **only** uses the isomorphism-invariance of first-order logic: if $$i:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}$$ is an isomorphism, $a_1,...,a_n\in\mathcal{A}$, and $\varphi(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a formula, then we must have $$\mathcal{A}\models\varphi(a_1,...,a_n)\quad\iff\quad \mathcal{B}\models\varphi(i(a_1),...,i(a_n)).$$ For first-order logic this can be proved by induction on the complexity of $\varphi$, but isomorphism invariance is usually taken as part of the$^1$ **definition** of a logic. Thus, we have:

> There is no logic according to which the successor function is definable in $\mathcal{Z}$.

Of course there are limitations to the automorphism approach. For example, the "unit distance" relation **is** fixed by all automorphisms of $\mathcal{Z}$, and in fact is definable over $\mathcal{Z}$ in either of the logics $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ or $\mathsf{SOL}$ (infinitary and second-order logic, respectively). So to show that the unit distance relation is not first-order definable over $\mathcal{Z}$ we have to do some work.

---

$^1$OK, this isn't really accurate: there are many different definitions out there, so what I wrote doesn't really parse. However, all the various notions that I'm aware of agree on this. For what it's worth, the one I think about most is the notion of **regular logic**, for which see the end of [Ebbinghaus/Flum/Thomas' Mathematical Logic](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387942582) or the beginning of [the collection Model-theoretic logics](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Model-Theoretic-Logics/toc/pl/1235417263).

Comment: Thanks.  I would not have been able to write an answer as useful as this.