# Can natural numbers with multiplication alone define the order relation?

Tags: model-theory

Consider the set $\mathbb{N}$ of natural numbers, including $0$. The structure $(\mathbb{N};+,\cdot)$ can define the standard order relation $\leq$. In fact, you don't even need multiplication to define the order relation. That raises the question, is it possible to define the standard order relation in the structure $(\mathbb{N};\cdot)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any permutation of the primes extends to an automorphism of $(\mathbb{N};\cdot)$. Since we can permute primes without preserving order (to put it mildly), this means that the ordering is not definable in $(\mathbb{N};\cdot)$ via *any* logic, let alone first-order logic.

*(OK, that's not quite fair - there isn't a universally agreed upon definition of "logic." However, any of the usual notions - e.g. "regular logic" a la Ebbinghaus/Flum/Thomas - have as a required property **isomorphism invariance**. The above applies to any such logic.)*

To put this "logic-independence" claim in perspective, consider $\mathfrak{C}:=(\mathbb{N};\mathsf{suc})$ where $\mathsf{suc}$ is the successor map. The structure $\mathfrak{C}$ is rigid, so automorphism-based arguments cannot be used here. Moreover, $<$, $+$, and $\cdot$ are each definable in $\mathfrak{C}$ via *second-order* logic. However, none of them is $\mathsf{FOL}$-definable in $\mathfrak{C}$.  Showing this latter point requires a more complicated argument. Basically, the point is that while automorphism-based arguments don't always succeed in proving non-definability results, when they do they prove extremely strong non-definability results.

Comment: Separately, I believe that this exact point has come up repeatedly in your prior questions, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4196959/can-additive-inverse-by-itself-define-binary-subtraction) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4114129/can-successor-be-defined-in-mathbbz). In general, if you're curious whether something is definable, always start by thinking about the (orbits of the action of the) automorphism group.