# $+$ can't define $div$

Tags: model-theory

This is a natural follow-up to my previous question, here: [Can natural numbers with multiplication alone define the order relation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4296719/can-natural-numbers-with-multiplication-alone-define-the-order-relation). In the structure $(\mathbb{N};+)$, can one define the relation $div$, that is, $x$ is a divisor of $y$? I believe it cannot, but I don't see how to prove it.

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing some nuance here but would this work?
$$
x \mid y \stackrel{\text{def.}}{\iff} \exists k \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } y = \sum_{i=1}^k x
$$

Comment: @PrincessEev That's not expressible in first-order logic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct that this cannot be done (in first-order logic, anyways). However, since the structure $(\mathbb{N};+)$ is rigid (= has no nontrivial automorphisms), proving this takes more work than the easier result you mention in the OP.

It turns out that in the structure $(\mathbb{N};+)$ - whose complete theory is [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) - every definable set is *eventually periodic* (this can be proved by quantifier elimination after passing to a stronger language; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211149/presburger-arithmetic/2211227#2211227)). This lets us show that $div$ is not definable in $(\mathbb{N};+)$: from $div$ we can define the set of primes, and that set is not eventually periodic.